# Meaning of "no less than" in a specific sentence

Tags: meaning, idioms

> For the monument to Newton’s pebble-collecting child is **no less than**
>   the modern world.

This sentence is extracted from *the Economist*.
I googled and found that A is no less than B means A and B are both in a high importance or they are both in a high quantity. And usually A can compare with B because they are in a same or a similar catalog.

However, in this sentence, I don't see **the monument** is a similar thing with **the modern world.** And I found it is meaningless if this sentence means that the monument and the modern world is in a same importance to Newton's pebble-collecting. Given the context, I thought that it means the whole modern world is one of the most important monument of Newton’s pebble-collecting child. Am I correct? If so, how to understand the meaning of no less than?

The whole paragragh is

> Does it all matter, a cynic might ask? Will humans really be better
>   off for knowing such things? The answer, written on the tomb, in St
>   Paul’s Cathedral, of Newton’s contemporary, Sir Christopher Wren, is:
>   “If you seek his monument, look around you.” For the monument to
>   Newton’s pebble-collecting child is no less than the modern world.

This is the [link of the article.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi02Y6N0a7JAhWBEpQKHafkAeUQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.economist.com%2Fnews%2Fleaders%2F21660537-science-has-remade-world-scientists-are-not-finished-yet-life-multiverse-and&usg=AFQjCNG6bfaCbykm9AQoW8MpAgB4XN8VTQ&sig2=u9Z8YMpfLyv5Do6uvblnPQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "no less than" has a slightly more idiomatic meaning.  It is meant to actually equate the two things.  It is stating that **the modern world** *is* the **monument to Newton's pebble-collecting child**.

You might expect the monument to be something smaller or less impactful, which is why the phrase "no less than" is used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track in understanding this.  In this sentence, **no less than** is a slightly less common way of saying **[nothing less than](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nothing-less-than)**.  "Nothing less than" is a way of saying "truly" or "nothing other than", which is a way of emphasizing the truth of an identity.

So the meaning, in the context of the paragraph, is

> The monument to Newton's pebble-collecting child is **nothing other than** the modern world - that is, the modern world is the monument to Newton's child.